# When to clean ReferenceQueue? Cleaned by system?

Tags: java, reference, queue

```
ReferenceQueue<Integer> queueObj = new ReferenceQueue<Integer>();
WeakReference<Integer> referenceObj = new WeakReference<Integer>(new Integer(1), queueObj);
```

I understand above like this,

- First, create WeakReference **referenceObj** object for **new Integer(1)** object.
- Second, system move **referenceObj** object into **queueObj**  object. Now **queueObj** has **referenceObj** element.
- Third, system GC the **new Integer(1)** object, and clear **queueObj** object. Now **queueObj** is empty.

Correctly?

EDIT:

- First, create WeakReference **referenceObj** object for **new Integer(1)** object.
- Second, system move **referenceObj** object into **queueObj**  object. Now **queueObj** has **referenceObj** element, **new Integer(1)** object has be collected by system.
- Third, some program detect **queueObj**  whether is empty or not. if not, you know some referent was collected, and you can iterate **queueObj** to handle **referenceObj**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and second, correct. Third, incorrect. It is up to you to process the ReferenceQueue, remove entries, act on whatever the entry means to your application, etc. For example, WeakHashMap processes the ReferenceQueue in the background to know when to remove items from the map.

Comment: @boiledwater No, not particularly, but in any case I don't see any value in just mangling what it already says in the Javadoc in a vain attempt to rephrase it. I suggest you direct your energies into understanding what it already says.